# (Django) How to assign unique values to each user for something linked by ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

My group project for school has us building a school management system. I have the following models:

Student:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User.is_student = True
    enrolled_courses = models.ManyToManyField(Session, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.last_name}, {self.user.first_name}'
```

Session:

```py
class Session(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    course_date_end = models.DateTimeField()

    def session_id(self):
        new_session_date = self.course_date_start.strftime('%Y')
        return f'{new_session_date}{self.course.number}{self.pk}'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.course.number} - {self.course.title} - {self.session_id()}'
```

Assignment:

```py
class Assignment(models.Model):
    session_link = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    due_date = models.DateField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total_points = models.IntegerField()
    points_earned = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    objective = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

The problem right now is if I save one value of `points_earned` to a user, it saves that value to all, since they're linked by the FK.

What's the best way to handle it so each Student can have their own score for each assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want each Student to have their own score for each assignment,then a solution would be to have a table to keep track of the score with those two models as foreign keys.

Use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

```
class StudentAssignment(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points_earned = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't think of something like that. That makes complete sense.